# Unknown key: :order in Mailboxer Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mailboxer

I am currently trying to use the Mailboxer Gem. I have added the following line in my Gemfile:

```
gem "mailboxer"
```

In the konsole I did these:

```
$ bundle install
$ rails g mailboxer:install
$ rake db:migrate
$ rails g mailboxer:views
```

and have added `acts_as_messageable` in my user.rb. However, I am getting this error

[image]

I tried replacing the gem in Gemfile from `gem 'mailboxer''` to `gem 'mailboxer', github: 'mailboxer/mailboxer'` but I get this message when I bundle install

```
git://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer.git (at master@0e41d6a) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
```

How can I fix this and make the mailboxer work in my rails application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I should add the following methods in user.rb besides the line `acts_as_messageable`:

```
  acts_as_messageable

  def name 
    self.name
  end 

  def mailboxer_email(object)
    nil
  end
```

I used the following for the Gemfile:

```
gem 'mailboxer', '~> 0.14.0'
```

The two errors I had from previous tries are now gone.